# Clojure core.logic : nafc and ground

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, minikanren, negation-as-failure

I'm representing a simple data-base in Clojure's core.logic.

There are two predicates : page(p) and link(p,q).

page(p) represents the existence of pages in a wiki called p

link(p,q) represents that page p contains a link to page q.

I'm now trying to query this database to find

- a) broken links (that is links in page p, for which there's no page q), and
- b) orphaned pages (pages that have no links to them)

My code for these queries is this :

```
(defn broken-links []
  (pldb/with-db @facts
    (logic/run* [p q]
      (link p q)
      (logic/nafc page q)
      )))

(defn orphans []
  (pldb/with-db @facts
    (logic/run* [p q]
      (logic/nafc link p q)
      (page q)
      )))
```

broken-links is working as expected, but orphans is giving me a list of :- symbols.

I'm assuming that this has something to do with nafc's limitation. According to the documentation :

> EXPERIMENTAL: negation as failure constraint. All arguments to the
>   goal c  must be ground. If some argument is not ground the execution
>   of this constraint  will be delayed.

And these are "delayed" because they are not "ground".

Can someone explain what ground really means here. I know it's "has no free variables" but I still don't really understand what that means in this context.

Secondly, how should I write this orphans query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of `nafc`, non-ground inputs are handled by giving non-ground outputs, so to get meaningful answers your inputs "must be ground." It cannot negate a constraint involving non-ground values.

For example, this program gives all possible values of `q` where `q` satisfies `emptyo`:

```
(run* [q]
  (emptyo q))
;=> (())
```

If we ask for all possible values of `q` that don't satisfy `emptyo` we get this:

```
(run* [q]
  (nafc emptyo q))
;=> ((_0 :- (clojure.core.logic/nafc #object[clojure.core.logic$emptyo 0x212442c1 "clojure.core.logic$emptyo@212442c1"] _0)))
```

A simplified phrasing is `((_0 :- (nafc emptyo _0)))`, which means there's only one answer but it could be *any* value that satisfies the RHS constraint. The logic program can't give us ground values because it doesn't know every possible non-empty list.

Here's an example DB setup for completeness:

```
(pldb/db-rel page q)
(pldb/db-rel link p q)
(def facts
  (pldb/db
    [page 'a]
    [page 'b]
    [page 'z]
    [link 'a 'b]
    [link 'b 'c]))
```

And your working broken-link program:

```
;; find links to non-pages
(pldb/with-db facts
  (run* [p q]
    (link p q)
    (nafc page q)))
;=> ([b c])
```

Here's a way to write the orphaned page program:

```
;; find pages without incoming links
(pldb/with-db facts
  (run* [q]
    (fresh [p]
      (page q)
      (conda
        [(link p q) fail]
        [succeed]))))
;=> (a z)
```

The negation here is expressed with `conda` to form a kind of *if-else* logic: *if* there is a link to page `q` we `fail` *else* we `succeed`.

Also note the use of `fresh` to introduce a logic variable `p` that isn't part of the desired answer output, since we only care about orphaned page values.

Comment: OK. So if I understand correctly, in my orphans, the problem is that p could be any of an infinite number of things. And "not anything" needs you to instantiate (even if lazily) the "anything" before you test the "not" of it?

Comment: @interstar yes I think your intuition is correct, but I struggle to use the right terms to describe some of these concepts. Highly recommend working through [The Reasoned Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/reasoned-schemer)!